# How to add two authentication on single express Route User.route('/').get((req,res,next)=>{ }) in this?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local, passport-jwt

I have two passport-jwt authentication

1. verifyUser
2. verifyPartner

I want my partner of added places are accessible to user as well as for partner based on authentication.

here some code that I used but it is respond unauthorize:

Route:
partnerRoute.js

```
const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
const Partner=require('../model/partner');
const Place=require('../model/place');
const auth=require('../authentication/auth');
const permission=require('../authentication/verifypermission');
const place = require('../model/place');

const partnerRouter=express.Router();
partnerRouter.use(bodyParser.json());

partnerRouter.route('/login')
.post((req,res,next)=>{
   Partner.findOne({email:req.body.email})
   .then((data)=>{
       if(auth.authenticate(req.body.password,data.hash_password))
       {
           res.end(auth.getToken({_id: data._id}));
       }
   })
   .catch((err)=>{
       console.log(err);
   })
});
partnerRouter.route('/register')
.post((req,res,next)=>{
    Partner.findOne({email:req.body.email})
   .then((data)=>{
       if(data)
       {
            res.end('Partner already exist with Email '+req.body.email);
       }
       else
       {
            Partner.findOne({contact:req.body.contact})
            .then((data)=>{
                if(data)
                {
                    res.end('Partner already exist with Contact '+req.body.contact);
                }
                else{
                    Partner.create(req.body)
                    .then((data)=>{
                            res.json({"Message":"Partner Successfully Created."})
                    })
                    .catch((err)=>{
                        console.log(err);
                    });
                }
            })
            .catch((err)=>{
                console.log(err);
            });
       }
   })
   .catch((err)=>{
       console.log(err);
   });

});

partnerRouter.route('/places/:partnerid')
.get(auth.verifyPartner,auth.verifyUser, (req,res,next)=>{
    permission.verifyPermission(req.user._id,req.params.partnerid,(err,data)=>{ // verifyPermission just use to check role of users.
        if(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
        if(data=='Permission_granted')
        {
            place.find({partner_id:req.params.partnerid})
            .then((data)=>{
                res.json(data);
            })
            .catch((err))
        }
        else{
            res.end(data)
        }
    })
})
module.exports=partnerRouter;
```

userRoute.js

```
const express=require('express');
const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
const User=require('../model/user');
const User_detail=require('../model/user_detail');
const auth=require('../authentication/auth');
const permission=require('../authentication/verifypermission');

const usersRouter = express.Router();

usersRouter.use(bodyParser.json());

usersRouter.route('/login')
.post((req,res,next) => {
   User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
   .then((userdata)=>{
        if(userdata)
        {
            if(auth.authenticate(req.body.password,userdata.hash_password))
            {                      
                res.end(auth.getToken({_id: userdata._id}));
            }
            else{
                res.end("Password Missmatch")
            }   
        }
        else
        {
            res.end("Check your email address");
        }
   })
   .catch((err)=>{
       console.log(err);
   })
}); 

usersRouter.route('/register')
.post((req,res,next)=>{
    User.findOne({email: req.body.email})
    .then((data)=>{
            if(data)
            {   
                res.end("User Already Exist with email: "+req.body.email);
            }
            else
            {
            User.findOne({contact: req.body.contact})
            .then((data)=>{
                if(data){
                    res.end("User Already Exist with contact number: "+req.body.contact)
                }
                else
                {
                    if(req.body.password)
                    {
                        req.body.hash_password=auth.encryptPassword(req.body.password);
                    }
                    User.create(req.body)
                    .then((data)=>{
                        res.json({"message": "user Successfully created"});
                    })
                    .catch((err)=>{
                        console.log(err);
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    });
});

module.exports= usersRouter;
```

Authentication
auth.js

```
const jwt=require("jsonwebtoken");
const bcrypt=require("bcrypt");
// const passport=require('passport');
var Passport = require('passport').Passport,
    passport = new Passport(),
    partnerPassport = new Passport();
const ExtractJwt=require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const JwtStrategy=require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const User=require("../model/user");
const Partner = require("../model/partner");

module.exports.getToken = function(user) {
    return jwt.sign(user, '12345-67890-09876-54321',
        {expiresIn: 3600});
};
module.exports.encryptPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10);
};
module.exports.authenticate = function(password,hash_password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password,hash_password);
};

var opts={}
    opts.secretOrKey = '12345-67890-09876-54321';
    opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();

module.exports.Jwtpassport=passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts,
    function(jwt_payload,done){
        // console.log("JWT payload: ", jwt_payload);
        User.findOne({_id: jwt_payload._id},function(err,userdata){
            if(err)
            {
                return done(err, false);
            }
            if(userdata)
            {
                return done(null, userdata);
            }
            else
            {
                return done(null, false);
            }
        })

}))

module.exports.Jwtpartnerpassport=partnerPassport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts,
    function(jwt_payload,done){
        // console.log("JWT payload: ", jwt_payload);
        Partner.findOne({_id: jwt_payload._id},function(err,partnerdata){
            if(err)
            {
                return done(err, false);
            }
            if(partnerdata)
            {
                return done(null, partnerdata);
            }
            else
            {
                return done(null, false);
            }
        })
}))

module.exports.verifyUser = passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false});
module.exports.verifyPartner = partnerPassport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false});
```

Model
user.js

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const bcrypt=require('bcrypt');

const userSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    firstname:
    {
        type:String,
        require: true,
        trim:true,
        min:3,
        max:15
    },
    lastname:
    {
        type:String,
        require: true,
        trim:true,
        min:3,
        max:15
    },
    email:
    {
        type:String,
        require: true,
        trim:true,
        unique:true,
        lowercase:true
    },
    contact:
    {
        type:String,
        require: true,
        unique:true
    },
    hash_password:
    {
        type:String,
        require:true
    },
    role:
    {
        type:String,
        enum:['user','admin'],
        default:'user'
    },
    profile_picture:
    {
        type:String
    },
    status:
    {
        type:Boolean,
        default:1
    }

},{ timestamps:true });

userSchema.virtual('password')
.set(function(password){
    this.hash_password=bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10);
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
```

partner.js

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const bcrypt=require('bcrypt');

const partnerSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    firstname:
    {
        type:String,
        require: true,
        trim:true,
        min:3,
        max:15
    },
    lastname:
    {
        type:String,
        require: true,
        trim:true,
        min:3,
        max:15
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        require: true,
        trim:true,
        unique:true,
        lowercase:true
    },
    contact:{
        type:String,
        require: true,
        unique:true
    },
    hash_password:{
        type:String,
        require:true
    },
    profile_picture:
    {
        type:String
    },
    status:
    {
        type:Boolean,
        default:1
    }
},{ timestamps:true });

partnerSchema.virtual('password')
.set(function(password){
    this.hash_password=bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10);
});

module.exports=mongoose.model("Partner",partnerSchema)
```

place.js

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose')

const placeSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    partner_id:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Partner'
    },
    title:{
        type:String,
        require:true,
        trim:true,
        unique:true,
        lowercase:true,
        min:3,
        max:15
    },
    city:{
        type:String,
        require: true,
        lowercase:true
    },
    state:{
        type:String,
        require: true,
        lowercase:true
    },
    country:{
        type:String,
        require: true,
        lowercase:true
    },
    pincode:{
        type:String,
        require: true
    },
    category:{
        type:String,
        require: true,
        lowercase:true
    },
    sub_category:{
        type:String,
        require: true,
        lowercase:true
    },
    description:{
        type:String,
        require: true,
        lowercase:true
    },
    address:{
        type:String,
        require: true,
        lowercase:true
    },
    nearest_railway_station:{
        type:String,
        require: true,
        lowercase:true
    },
    nearest_airport:{
        type:String,
        require: true,
        lowercase:true
    },
    image:{
        type:String,
        require: true,
    },
    Product_sale:{
        type:Boolean,
        default:0
    },
    status:{
        type:Boolean,
        default:0
    }
},{timestamps:true})

module.exports=mongoose.model('Place',placeSchema);
```

index.js

```
const express= require('express');
const http= require('http');
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
var Passport = require('passport').Passport,
    passport = new Passport(),
    partnerPassport = new Passport();

const app= express();

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(partnerPassport.initialize());

const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 2000;
const url="mongodb://localhost:27017"

mongoose.connect(
    'mongodb://localhost:27017/susvagatam', 
    {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useFindAndModify:false
    }
).then(()=>{
    console.log('database connected');
});

const partnerRouter = require('./route/partnerRouter.js');
const usersRouter = require('./route/usersRouter.js');


app.use('/partners', partnerRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);


const server= http.createServer(app)
server.listen(port,hostname,()=>{
    console.log('server is runing')
});
```

if I add only partner then work fine or if I add only User then also work fine.but when add both it does not work fine. responded unauthorized.

Single authentication are work properly but two authentication not work.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you need here is `authorization` as opposed to `authentication`.

Let `verifyUser` handle the authentication while `verifyPartner` handles the authorization for partners only.

Refactor your `verifyPartner` to look like this:

```js
module.exports.verifyPartner = (req, res, done) => {
  Partner.findOne({ _id: req.params.partnerid }, (err, partnerdata) => {
    if (err) {
      return done(err, false);
    }

    if (partnerdata) {
      return done(null, partnerdata);
    }

    return done(null, false);
  });
};
```

And on the `'/places/:partnerid'` route where you're using it as a middleware make sure you call `verifyUser` first before `verifyPartner`.

Like this:

```js
partnerRouter.route('/places/:partnerid')
  .get(auth.verifyUser, auth.verifyPartner, (req,res,next)=> {...})
```

This way authentication happens and the `user` is verified first before proceeding to check if the user is an authorized partner.

Comment: I am Update my code as you given solution but it is does not work for partner login. its is return **Unauthorized**. For single authenntication its return **Cannot read property '_id' of undefined**. My updated code is:                           **auth.js** ``module.exports.verifyUser = passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false});
module.exports.verifyPartner = (req, res, done) => {...};`` 
**partnerRoute.js**          ``partnerRouter.route('/places/:partnerid')
.get(auth.verifyUser,auth.verifyPartner,(req,res,next)=>{...}) ``